# collection_radio_buttons from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**How can I select a value from a pre-defined collection in a model, using collection_radio_buttons?**

I tried

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :lang_lvl, Language.language_levels, :language_level, :language_level #does not work
= f.select :lang_lvl, Language.language_levels, include_blank: true #works
```

The data source is defined in a model Language.rb:

```
class Languages < ActiveRecord::Base
  LANGUAGE_LEVELS = [:"A1/Elem", :"A2/PreInt", :"B1/Int", :"B2/UpperInt", :"C1/Adv", :"C2/Prof", :"A1/Beg"]

  def self.language_levels
    LANGUAGE_LEVELS.map { |language_level| [language_level, language_level] }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd and 4th arguments of `collection_radio_buttons` specify the method used to extract value and text respectively. The function will try to call `[language_level, language_level].language_level` to convert the data because you're passing an array of arrays as a collection and `:language_level` to be called for each item in that sub-array.

If you don't want to change your model, you could try to change the code to this:

```
= f.collection_radio_buttons :lang_lvl, Language.language_levels, :first, :last
```